# Automating Instruments for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, scripting, automation, instruments, smoke-testing

We're interested to see if we can include Instruments-based leak testing as a part of our regular application smoke testing. What kind of scriptability is available for Instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruments is based on the [`dtrace`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html) framework. You might be able to use that directly, without the instruments GUI.

Comment: There is an `Automation template` which can run iOS simulator test using javascript. Is it possible to realize such functionality by means of `dtrace`? Thanks.